# How to remove 'ubuntu' option from os selection menu?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1, grub, mbr

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Dell Vostro 15 3546. Its has Windows 8.1 installed. I divided the 500 GB HDD in to 2 and installed Ubuntu in one partition. Due to some error in installation I had to reinstall it. 
Now the problems are: 
1. GRUB doesn't show. 
 
2. On entering OS selection menu by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or on entering BIOS  setup -> boot, 2 Ubuntu options are shown.

[image: UEFI boot menu with duplicate 'ubuntu' options]

I removed ubuntu folder from MBR partition. But still this shows.

How to remove this unwanted options and get GRUB OS selection menu?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to repair a damaged GRUB installation is to use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Boot your pc from the same Ubuntu medium which you used for the installation of 15.04, open a terminal, then issue the following commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

A GUI will open up, under most conditions the simplest choice (*Recommended repair (repairs most frequent problems)*) will be enough. Otherwise, you have more richer options, still from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

We can regard UEFI boot as a two stage boot process.

1. Firmware boot manager is executed which selects its first boot candidate depending on NVRAM boot variables.

**Usually first boot candidate is Windows boot manager**.

**To set another boot manager/loader as first boot candidate you should place it as FIRST in boot order using UEFI firmware setup manually**.

2. The selected OS(Windows/Linux) boot manager/loader then based on its own boot settings (Windows uses BCD store, GRUB uses grub.conf) presents a boot menu to the user.

Windows UEFI boot manager cannot chain load foreign OS like Linux (Microsoft has forbidden this by implementation).

GRUB can chain load Windows. So putting GRUB as first in NVRAM and configuring it for dual-boot (Linux/Windows) the user can then easily select an OS from GRUB boot menu.